# Is it true that Prof. Amann defines such that only right (or left) derivative exists is sufficient to have a derivative at a point?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

I'm reading about differentiation in textbook Analysis I by Amann.

> [image].

Consider $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$. Clearly, $0$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$.

Assume that $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists. Then $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim _{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists. This is because any sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_n \to 0$ contains only $x_n \ge 0$. As such, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ according to Prof. Amann.

Usually, other textbooks said that $f$ does not have derivative at $0$, but only has the **right** derivative at $0$. So I'm very confused.

I would like to ask if my understanding is correct! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's just a matter of taste.  Most would say that $f$ can only be "right differentiable" at 0, but you could indeed call that the derivative if you want...here comes the flame war.

Comment: Hi @Dzoooks, so one-sided derivative is sufficient to have derivative according to Prof. Amann, right?

Comment: It depends on interpretation here. If you consider $y=x*sqrt(x)$ then the derivative will give you perfectly zero for $x=0$. But (0,0) is an endpoint so do you allow the positive x axis to be a tangent?

Comment: The key point here is that this isn’t just any old one-sided derivative: it’s being computed at a boundary of the interval.

Comment: Hi @amd, I'm sorry but I'm unable to understand what is the problem with computing the derivative at a boundary of the interval. Could you please explain more?

Comment: The definition is correct as one needs to remember that a function is defined by domain and "formula" together, so for example $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable as a function on $[0,1]$, but not as a function on $[-1,1]$ since technically they are two different functions, having different domains, though they have same formula. In particular the notion of differentiability depends on the domain of the function, not only on its "formula". For complicated sets there is no easy way to think in terms of left, right etc derivatives, so we need the distinction above

Comment: For real intervals I agree the definition above is somewhat misleading, but that is the price one pays for having a general definition that applies for example to sets in the complex plane where we already have a much starker distinction between interior points where differentiability implies analyticity and boundary points where it gets complicated not like the one sided case in real intervals